# Share iTunes playlist with another computer (Different account)

Tags: itunes, music, sharing

I want to share my playlist with my friend. He can give me his apple ID. I have a big playlist on my computer. I have not made any changes in the Preferences yet. Help appleseeds?

Answer (score 1):

Drag the individual tracks to a USB key etc - this will initially lose the playlist data & only copy the tracks themselves.

To add an importable playlist to that, go to File > Library > Export Playlist, then save as M3U format & add to the USB key. Your friend can then add the entire playlist by dragging just the M3U file to his iTunes - the tracks will be copied in automatically.

Alternatively, you can export a playlist by burning to CD/DVD
Right click the playlist title & click Burn Playlist to Disk.
I'm not certain whether this will carry playlist information or just the tracks - it's been too long since I did it.

BTW - passing around AppleID information is **really** not recommended.
It's the way to lose control of your own devices, if ever used maliciously.

Comment: Actually I know this. But I was looking for a way to share them without any physical devices but through the internet. Is that possible? Thanks for the answer anyway man!

Comment: Live. No. Via email, dropbox etc, same as above.